# QGIS for Mac: Python dependencies

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, installation, python-2.7

I am developing a QGIS plugin in QGIS 2.18.15 on macOS 10.13.2 and I am having some troubles with Python libraries dependencies. More specifically, my plugin will require to use an external Python library which is already installed and working in my system (both for Python 2.7 and Python 3). The problem is that apparently QGIS uses its own different version of Python (Python 2.7.10) which is not equipped with the library I need.

How can I ask QGIS to use the default system version of Python?

As an alternative, how can I add external libraries to the QGIS Python 2.7.10?

Comment: QGIS from KyngChaos  use exclusively the Apple Python  preinstalled (2.7.10) with modules in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` (there are many answers to this question on GiS SE)

Comment: Is there any way to force QGIS to use another version of Python? Or, as an alternative, is there any way to add packages/libraries to Apple Python preinstalled (2.7.10) ?

Comment: With the KyngChaos version no. To  install libraries to  Apple Python,  it's like the other versions. (with `pip`, `easy_install` or `setup.py`)

Comment: My problem is that pip installs libraries to a different version of Python, and not to Apple Python (pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7) )

Comment: @gene users should never be installing packages in the Apple Python. It's a recipe for breaking parts of your operating system. Users should stick to `--user` installs and virtualenvs. The KyngChaos QGIS *should* support user installs.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case with the KyngChaos QGIS

Comment: The impossibility of setting which Python version to be used by QGIS is a huge limitation...

Comment: @user3352382 with only Apple Python in your PATH, run "python -m pip install package_name_here"